# What will occur at replace xml file on reading?

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I have a lrage **XML** file and i'm read it "on the fly" with **XMLReader**. All time process take up approx an 1 hour.

```
$xmlReader = new XMLReader();
$xmlReader->open($this->getPath());

while ($xmlReader->read() && $xmlReader->name !== 'category') ;

while ($xmlReader->name == 'category')
{
   // handler ...
}
```

What will occur if something **replace** this XML file on reading proccess?

Comment: You can do one thing convert `XML string` to `json` and `json` to `array`. I think you can quickly iterate over `array`.

Comment: @SahilGulati even XML 100+ mb? All process depends from database. It doesn't matter. I have more theory interest than practice.

Comment: I would expect the script to get a reading error and die. Try it out.

Comment: An hour for processing 100Mb seems incredibly slow. I would normally expect XML processing to run at something between 1-10Gb/min, depending on the application-level processing.

Comment: @MichaelKay it's good speed xD Because an XML file from 1C company. They nothing to know about normalization. Many relations and keys check in MySQL itself. Anyway it doesn't matter. Because the question about behavior PHP at "substitution" file on reading.